# Ad block Plus debugging, undertsanding code base

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension, adblock

I am working on a project which involves ad-detection. I wanted to leverage ad block plus code. But I am struggling with understanding it.

I am using adblock plus for chrome and using chrome debugger to step through the code, but whatever breakpoints i set inside most of the javascript files, the control is not getting there. I am only able to see the control going to include.preload.js. I have added the source folder to work space.

Also content script is showing only a few files and breakpoint set in inlcude.preload.js in content scripts is working, but breakpoints set anywhere else dont seem to get hit, not even if they are set in source tree.

Any pointers will be very helpful. I am struggling as I am new to this domain. If there are any books/resources to help understand the working of ad block plus better, please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried inserting `debugger;` statement in the code instead of setting breakpoints?

Comment: I am completely new to the debugging extensions and waas not aware of debugger; statement. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

include.preload.js and include.postload.js only contain the code that's being injected into the page. The core code of the extension is running in its background page which you can debug like this:

1. Go to chrome://extensions
2. Check the "Developer mode" checkbox in the top-right corner
3. Click on the "Background page" link underneath the Adblock Plus entry